# Set relation to many-to-many relationship

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this many-to-many relationship that works correctly. However, now I need to have another class with a relation to this many-to-many.

```
currencies = db.Table('currencies_many',
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('currency_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('currencies.id')),
    db.Column('bank_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('banks.id'))
)

class Bank(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'banks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bank_name = db.Column(db.String(300))
    currencies = db.relationship('Currency', secondary=currencies,
        backref=db.backref('banks', lazy='dynamic'))

class Currency(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'currencies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    currency_name = db.Column(db.String(300))
```

What I mean is, for example, an order, I need to have the association to many to many.

```
class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bank_currency_identification = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('currencies_many.id'))
```

How can I do that? In my example I don't have `db.relationship` for `bank_currency_identification`, it is correct?

Comment: You do have a foreign key. You don't need a relationship, at least I don't see why. Why are you trying to make it a many to many relationship? If you do need it to be a many to many, you could create another table like `currencies_many`

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand your question correctly, you want to reference the `currencies_many` table from your `orders` table. If so, you are correct in having a foreign key relationship with the `currencies_many` table.

However, down the road you may come into some trouble when you want to query `orders` from your `banks` table. I would suggest, although it seems redundant, to create a one-to-many relationship between `Order` and `Bank` as well as between `Order` and `Currency`.

```
bank_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bank.id'))
currency_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('currency.id'))
```

And then in the `Bank` class

```
orders = db.relationship('Order', backref='bank')
```

This gives you a much cleaner querying interface.

```
bank_orders = bank.orders
```

As well as makes your data model cleaner. It would be awkward to have to query orders from an intermediate table that also houses the currency. Just my two cents, but having an easy to understand Data model is better than making awkward relationships to save some redundancy.